# how to get Facebook user access token using only server side with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I want to get my Facebook account campaigns statistics every half an hour using Nodejs. for that i need user access token (a new one every request, because its expires). How can i do than only using server side?

Comment: You can not get a user access token without the user interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can request tokens using [Facebook's API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). However, in your case it should be enough to use an [application level token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) with the required permissions. You can generate it once (even manually, with a GET call) and it won't expire.

```
GET {api-path}/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: hey! tnx... you are talking about app access token. i need user access token.. i think... can i get campaigns and ads data and statistics with app access token?? it will be grate!!